# How to set correct backend URL in my vanilla frontend app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, cors

I am teaching myself full stack development using Nodejs.
I am starting out very simple with a vanilla (no frameworks) frontend, express backend and a postgres database. Both frontend and backend are in the same repo (to keep things simpel).
Here it is: https://github.com/mytzenka/skribblewords

I have everything working fine locally (with postgres running in a Docker). I have a local `.env` file which only contains the database connect string. Heroku has this same variable to provide *its* database connect string.

However I run into problems when deploying to Heroku. The deploy works fine. The backend starts succesfully and also connects with the database (thanks to Heroku's env variable for this). The frontend is also visible when I go to the live URL after deployment.

The frontend is served by the backend `app.js` like this:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/client/index.html`)})
```

However I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get the URL to the backend - which is now hardcoded as localhost in my frontend code - to be set correctly after deployment. The live URL is automatically generated by Heroku and will be different after each restart. I can't find an environment variable for this in the Heroku dashboard and even if there were one, I don't know how to load it as the following code doesn't work in my frontend code.

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

This is now in my frontend `index.js` code, which obviously needs to change after deployment.

```
const baseUrl = "http://localhost:3000" //TODO <-- HOW TO SET THIS WHEN DEPLOYED TO HEROKU?
```

I also have the reverse problem regarding CORS. How do I let the backend know what to put here - in `app.js` - after deployment to Heroku?

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',  //TODO <-- HOW TO SET THIS WHEN DEPLOYED ON HEROKU (WHEN NEEDED)?
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Yes, I have been Googling for answers already. Unfortunately almost all examples I find are based on React and too complex for my noob brain to understand. I don't want to use React (yet). I want to keep things as simple as possible for my first learning project.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by using this line of code in the frontend:

```
const baseUrl = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}:${window.location.port}`
```

And using a new ENV variable in Heroku for setting CORS

Probably not the best practice to do it this way, but at least now it works!